# Привести значение ссылки в uppercase с помощью regex

Tags: html

Есть много ссылок на сайте, вида

```
<a href="/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8f/">
```

Нужно привести к виду:

```
<a href="/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%D0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8F/">
```

Я нагуглил, что `\u` делает uppercase, но  как создать, чтобы все ссылки по типу href="" преобразовало в uppercase? Не знаком с регулярками

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В JS у строк есть метод:

```
String.prototype.toUpperCase()
```

Этот медод возвращает новую строку, у которой все символы в верхнем регистре. А регулярные выражения никак не изменяют строки, регулярные выражения - это шаблон

Comment: У меня много файлов сайта. Нужно на всех страницах поменять это.

Comment: Можно использовать такое выражение: 'href="[\S]{1,}"'

Comment: Это найти все строки ссылок. А как их привести в верхний регистр?

Comment: @Tip поставить `\U` и `\E` вокруг захваченных групп, но это работает не везде

Comment: @dIm0n Вокруг? Это как? 

href="[\S]{1,}\U\E" Так?

Comment: @Tip регулярное выражение - это шаблон, оно не может изменить что-то. Ты можешь только найти подстроку с помощью регулярного выражения

Comment: @Tip нет, их надо добавлять в заменяющей регулярке, примерно так в зависимости от инструмента `\U$1\E`

Comment: @Inventor можно менять в соответствии с регулярным выражением:
`str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function[, flags])`.
Возвращаемое значение -- новая строка с некоторыми или всеми сопоставлениями шаблона, заменёнными на заменитель.